# How to preserve white space in Bash arguments

Tags: bash, unix, command-line-arguments, arguments

I use the command:

```
cm1 cm2 arg1 arg2 'argument 3'
```

It first goes to `cm1`, which will then redirect `arg1 arg2 'argument 3'` to another file.

#### `/usr/bin/cm1`:

```
#! /bin/bash
# some script here
shift
cm2 $@
```

#### `/usr/bin/cm2`:

```
echo $#
# This returns 4 in lieu of 3 because the white space in 'argument 3' causes the argument to be split into two arguments.
```

So, how can I pass arguments from one script to another and make sure white space won't be read as an argument separator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you have to re-wrap it into quotes, like so:

```
#! /bin/bash
# some script here
shift
cm2 "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works on the simple example I gave. Now on the real script I am coding and that has more complex rerouting, arguments get broken at some point. But that means the error is coming from somewhere else... Thanks!

Comment: It may be that you split these args later based on default IFS which default value is "<space><tab><newline>"

Comment: I was looking for opposite behavior - how to force my script to iterate over arguments separated with spaces. In my script I had quoted reference ("$@") so all arguments were treated as one concatenated string. I replaced: >for path in "$@"< with: >for path in $@< and it worked. Thank you.