# Unable to preserve a multi-word argument surrounded by double-quotes as a single argument in a Bash function

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I've been stuck on this issue around variable expansion in Bash scripts where a multi-word argument surrounded by spaces is getting split into multiple arguments when passed down a chain of functions.

For example:

```
"this entire string"
```

becomes:

```
"this
entire
string"
```

Extracting out the arrangement of functions out of the code that it's causing the issue in, below is what I could come up with to reproduce the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The function that gets called from outside the script
wrapper_function () {
    echo "1: Parameter count: $#"
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "wrapper_function - $i"
    done
    actual_function $@
}

# The actual low-level function that does something useful
actual_function () {
    echo "2: Parameter count: $#"
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "actual_function - $i"
    done
}

# Setting the value of the 'problematic' argument
some_string="\"five-1 five-2\""

# Calling the function with a collated set of arguments
wrapper_function "one two three four ${some_string}"
```

On running this I would get:

```
1: Parameter count: 1
wrapper_function - one two three four "five-1 five-2"
2: Parameter count: 6
actual_function - one
actual_function - two
actual_function - three
actual_function - four
actual_function - "five-1
actual_function - five-2"
```

Instead, I expect:

```
1: Parameter count: 1
wrapper_function - one two three four "five-1 five-2"
2: Parameter count: 5
actual_function - one
actual_function - two
actual_function - three
actual_function - four
actual_function - "five-1 five-2"
```

Is there anything that I could do to get around this, maybe quoting some arguments or passing them around some other way?

*I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/400109/how-to-preserve-white-space-in-bash-arguments) that this one might look like a duplicate of but I think it's not.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do proper quoting

```
#! /bin/bash

function level3 {
    printf -- "-- Level3 ------\nGot %d arguments:\n" $#
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$arg"
    done
    printf -- "--------\n"
}

function level2 {
    printf -- "-- Level2 ------\nGot %d arguments:\n" $#
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$arg"
    done
    printf -- "--------\n"
    level3 "$@"
}

function level1 {
    printf -- "-- Level1 ------\nGot %d arguments:\n" $#
    for arg in "$@"
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$arg"
    done
    printf -- "--------\n"
    level2 "$@"
}

level1 "$@"
```

Gives:

```
>>./quotes a bc "\"abc def\""
-- Level1 ------
Got 3 arguments:
a
bc
"abc def"
--------
-- Level2 ------
Got 3 arguments:
a
bc
"abc def"
--------
-- Level3 ------
Got 3 arguments:
a
bc
"abc def"
--------
```

Comment: Alright, so now I have two potential solutions, and this might be the correct one. I'll try it out and let you know.

Comment: Update: It works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, after a lot of playing around, I finally solved it myself and I think this could really help someone else coming across this kind of an issue. The solution basically needed two changes:

1. The function `wrapper_function` needed to be called with two arguments instead of one. I would pass the first set of 'usual' arguments as a single string and then the 'problematic' argument as the second.
2. The function `actual_function` needed to pass around the two received arguments down the chain separately instead of referring the entire collection as `$@`.

The code now looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The function that gets called from outside the script
wrapper_function () {
    echo "1: Parameter count: $#"
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "wrapper_function - $i"
    done
    actual_function $1 "$2"
}

# The actual low-level function that does something useful
actual_function () {
    echo "2: Parameter count: $#"
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo "actual_function - $i"
    done
}

# Setting the value of the 'problematic' argument
some_string="\"five-1 five-2\""

# Calling the function with a collated set of arguments
wrapper_function "one two three four" "${some_string}"
```

And the output though a little different seems to do what I intended to do:

```
1: Parameter count: 2
wrapper_function - one two three four
wrapper_function - "five-1 five-2"
2: Parameter count: 5
actual_function - one
actual_function - two
actual_function - three
actual_function - four
actual_function - "five-1 five-2"
```

I hope someone would find this useful.

Comment: Not clear what your problem is but this is likely not the answer

Comment: Well, it seems to work for me. I have all the code pasted in the answer and it does prove that too that it at least works for my specific use-case. (From a naive bash scripter) Any enlightenment would be appreciated.